# I am getting the error "Program received signal: “SIGABRT” while trying to capture the part of screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a project where the particular part of the screen has to be saved as image.

I created a view named `customView`. I put an image view and label in this view and I used the following code to capture the image.

```
-(IBAction)saveButtonClicked
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, screenSize.width, screenSize.height, 8, 4*(int)screenSize.width, colorSpaceRef,
                                         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, screenSize.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    [(CALayer*)self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);  
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
}
```

**filePath** is /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/388C6FB6-9D76-4507-9D3A-03D615BB63AD/Documents/savedImage.png. I created `filepath` using the following code

```
NSArray *documentsArray=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docPath=[documentsArray objectAtIndex:0];
filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try Reset IOS Simulator and clean product in XCode.